# How add sku attribute to TotalsItemInterface?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, interface

I want to add sku attribute to `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemInterface` (and `Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals`). This attribute is not my and default for magento, but he turned off from the interface. If I directly add code to this file I have sku attribute in "Order Summary" block in checkout step 1.

But I want use `extension_attributes.xml` for except touching core files.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemInterface">
        <attribute code="sku" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

It not working. Next I try execute `setup:di:compile`. No working.

What I need to do?